# Generic Rest API design for internal applications

Tags: rest

I am designing REST API for  internal applications.
I have many database CURD operations and don't want to define each endpoints for different tables. so I came up with the 2 generic endpoints,

```
/api/1.0/hub/generic/query.json
/api/1.0/hub/generic/NonQuery.json
```

So a POST request with JSON obj {'sql': 'insert ...', 'param': [...] } will serve all CURD operations. Is this design against best practices?

Thanks,

Comment: If you really want to serve _all_ CRUD operations via `POST` then it is even against rather basic REST principles.

Comment: Having a single endpoint for all resources is clearly against REST too. To my understanding this is just a simple HTTP proxy to a SQL database.